# Haproxy 1.6 - Front end rule based on IP address without domain

Tags: haproxy

In my frontend rules of Haproxy, I'd like to select a backend when the client is reaching haproxy with the IP address and not with the domain name.

Basically, if the user target Haproxy with `1.2.3.4` instead of `mysite.com`, I will redirect on a specific backend.

I tried the following but the acl was not matching:

```
acl nodomain hdr(host) -i 1.2.3.4
use_backend backendnodomain if nodomain
```

Comment: Does the client/browser use HTTP/1.1? With HTTP/1.0 the Host header is not mandatory.

Comment: All the clients are using HTTP/1.1. In the case I was describing in my question, the client is not a browser but another server and probably using curl.

Comment: A TCP capture would help to see what headers you are getting.

Comment: Will arrange for that. Do we agree that the acl in the question should be working?